# MySQL: how to extract multiple text files from my MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I need to extract data from my MySQL database into multiple text files.

I have a table with 4 columns: `UserID, UserName, Tag, Score`.

I need to create a text file for each Tag, with the **userID**, the **userName** and **score** (**ordered by score**).

For example

```
Tag1.txt
234922 John 35
234294 David 205
392423 Patrick 21

Tag2.txt
234922 John 35
234294 David 205
392423 Patrick 21
```

and so on...

Edited: Sample: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/expertsTable.png

Comment: Are you doing this in a database management program such as SQLyog or PHPMyAdmin, or is there a program that you are writing to perform the query and write the file?

Comment: yeah I'm using PHPMYAdmin and Sequel Pro for mac. They write files based on queries... i dunno what kind information you need.. ask me

Comment: Ok, that helps, because the file-writing part is taken care of for you, you just need to know what the SQL query syntax should be. Then my next two questions are: 1) Are there as many tags as there are records? and 2) Can you provide a small sample table?

Comment: Not sure about question 1. Yes there is a tag for each row. Each user has a score for each tag. The same user cannot have 2 scores over 1 tag. There are not empty fields. Question 2. I've updated my post.

Comment: This helps greatly because the tag field is a sort of category. If I can't come up with an answer for you, hopefully someone will be able to based on this new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write code for the normal mysql_fetch_object() function and write file function from PHP can be used to solve your problem. See below.

```
$Query = "select * from Table1";
$row = $mysql_query($Query);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_object($row))
{
    $filecontent = $rs->userid . ' '. $rs->username . ' '. $rs->score;
    $myFile = $rs->tag.".txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = $filecontent."\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a query that will write every file for you automatically, unless you use stored procedures or a cursor of some kind (I'm unfamiliar with those for the most part).

However here are two queries you may find useful:

This will select the top scorer from each tag and list them:

```
SELECT userid, name, score, tag FROM users
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This will select all the scores from a given tag (z-wave in this example), in order of score:

```
DECLARE @TagName AS STRING;
SET @TagName = "z-wave";
SELECT userid, NAME, score, tag FROM users
WHERE tag = @TagName
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Note that in your example desired results, the scores do not seem to be in order.

Comment: hi, thanks for this snippets. I was actually studying how to use your second query together with the php code of PHP-Prabhu. Should I maybe build a table with all tags and run php script to retrieve the tag name and run your query for each tag ?

Comment: I think that's the path I would take. Simply query the table for a list of tags (select distinct(tag) from users) then create a loop using that list which runs the second query, outputting the results of each iteration to a file named after the tag.